# ROS installation: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, installation, ros, windows-subsystem-for-linux

According to ros wiki, to set up environment,
I typed

```
echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

The error is

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash:.:8: no such file or directory: /home/pikashun/setup.sh
```

In `~/.bashrc` file, there is the `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` line.

I use Ubuntu on WSL.
How can I improve?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of sourcing the bash file, try sourcing the zsh file as `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.zsh`.

Comment: I think @ShubhamAgrawal's answer is the right way to go, as it allows you to keep working in zsh.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue. The problem is not due to `setup.bash` either `~/.bashrc` but the shell that you are using. It turned out that you may be using a different shell than `bash` (i.e., `zsh`). When you are executing the `setup.bash` of ROS, `zsh` interprets the following command (whici is in `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`) differently:

```
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
```

It is setting the `_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR` to your user directory. That is why you are getting error, cause you using the wrong path:
`/home/user/setup.bash` instead of `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`

To check whether this is the issue of your problem, you can check the shell that you are using by execute the following in the terminal:

```
echo $0; echo $SHELL
```

It may return something like:

```
zsh
/bin/zsh
```

To switch from `zsh` to `bash`, use:

```
exec bash
```

Once done this, you can use source without any problem.

And to switch back to your previous shell (assuming that is `zsh`), just use:

```
exec zsh
```

Answer (score 2):

The file `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` does nothing but loading `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh` from the same directory. I might be that you are not running `bash` ([check which terminal you run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal)), or that WSL has some different behavoiour than expected.
However, your can just alter your append command like so:

```
 echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

or in your case, since the entry exists already in your `~/.bashrc`, edit the line  `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh`

Answer (score 1):

The packages or files were not actually downloaded from the "http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu". To overcome this error first open terminal

1. check your directory `pwd`. If your directory is like /home/'Your PC Name' it won't actually work.
2. Change the directory : Type `cd /`
3. Continue the installation process from start which mentioned in "http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu"

melodic can change to kinetic or other version if you wish